# Dependency injection and ownership issue

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

I have a code base where constructor dependency injection is used a lot, mainly because it makes testing much easier. So there’s a lot of code like this:

```
class Client
{
    public:
    Client(DependencyBase& s) : s_{s}{}
    private:
    DependencyBase& s_;
};
```

The problem with this approach is that now parent context must construct and own all dependencies although it has no use for them. It also makes the code ugly as constructor initializer or argument lists may become very long. Is there a better way to structure the code to avoid this problem? Unfortunately dynamic memory allocation is not allowed...

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: You could perhaps templatize client with each dependency type and store the dependencies within the client instead of a reference.

Comment: Perhaps wrap the dependencies in a `bundle` type of class so that only a single parameter is passed.  Don't forget to label the constructor `explicit`

Comment: By your description it seems to me personally that it's not dependency injection that is a problem in your project. In my experience the most typical approach would be to use the parent context as injected dependency itself instead of making and owning lots of other objects for the sole purpose of injecting it as dependency. Is seems to me "...it has no use for them" is the sign of a problem (or maybe a conscious trade off). Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use dynamic memory and still want the `Client` class to own the dependency, injecting it as a template parameter is an option, for example:

```
template <typename Dependency>
class Client
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    Dependency s;
};
```

or if you need parameters

```
template <typename Dependency>
class Client
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit Client(Args&&... args) : s{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

    // ...
private:
    Dependency s;
};
```

To instantiate it, you need to pass the class of the dependency, plus its parameters:

```
Client<MyDependency> client{"foo", 42};
```

The effect is that `client` will internally have the dependency

```
MyDependency s{"foo", 42};
```

The advantage of template parameters is that it will not create a performance overhead, but it is more verbose. Also you will have to expose the class implementation in the header, which is a consideration if the increased compile time is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I was thinking about option 1 too, used with `std::is_base_of`. But as you said it would mean moving entire class implementation to the header file which has not only impact on compile time but binary size too, and sometimes there’s a LOT of these template parameters :) second example won’t work I think because if there’s more than 1 dependency, how do you differentiate which constructor args go to which object?

Comment: @xba I agree, with multiple dependencies, using perfect forwarding will not work out-of- the-box. Perhaps you could pass in an additional parameter, which acts as a factory (some class/struct with a static function to create the dependency, or some lambda function if the arguments are only known at runtime). Or passing std::initializer_list for each dependency could work. I think, it should not create runtime overhead. Yet in both cases, you have the same drawbacks; in regard to verbosity even amplified. I fear that it will make the code hard to understand because of the added noise.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a better way to structure the code to avoid this problem?

Some options:

1. Have an extra constructor which takes an rvalue-reference for `Dependency`, with a default value, so you can call it as though it was a no-args constructor. You'll also need to store your DependencyBase then...:

   ```
   class Client {
   public:
       Client(DependencyBase& s) : s_{s} {}
       Client(DependencyBase&& s) : s_{s} {}
   private:
       DependencyBase s_;
   };
   ```
2. Have a default constructor, which constructs a `DependencyBase`; if that's not possible - you're going to have to either construct it or provide the arguments for constructing it, outside the `Client`, anyway. So,

   ```
   class Client {
   public:
       Client() : s_{arguments,go,here} {}
   // or:
   //  Client() : s_{function_which_creates_a_DependencyBase()} {}
       Client(DependencyBase&& s) : s_{s} {}
   private:
       DependencyBase s_;
   };
   ```
3. If you want *both* the possibility of changing an external `DependencyBase` *and* having your own `DependencyBase`, you could have a `std::variant<DependencyBase,std::reference_wrapper<DependencyBase>> s_`, and your constructors would initialize the first (given an rvalue reference) or the second (given an lvalue reference). This will make life a bit more complicated inside `Client` but simpler on the outside.

> Unfortunately dynamic memory allocation is not allowed...

Your code didn't seem to use dynamic memory allocation anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I wasn’t maybe very clear that `DependencyBase` is a base class for some object. So (correct me if I’m wrong but) in option `1` slicing will occur, in option `2` the same plus first 1st constructor will attempt to create a base class object but I need specialization. Option `3` is probably a no-go because `std::variant` was introduced in C++17, but could you elaborate on that option? What do you mean by “first” and “second”?

Comment: Also I mentioned that dynamic memory allocation is not allowed because the problem is very easy to solve if it was - I could just store pointer to `DerivedBase` in `Client` and initialize it with `new` in call to constructor. I could probably implement some semi-static memory allocator but I’m curious if there are other options

Comment: @xba: Your example does not have `Class` inheriting from `DependencyBase`. In fact, if that were the case, your question would not make much sense, because in that case it would not be true that the parent "doesn't have much use" for a `DependencyBase`. It has use for a `DependencyBase` by having use for a member of a subtype of it, a `Client`.